# I am getting error "SyntaxError: Expected token ')' " in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have a pretty simple javascript in an external file myjs.js

```
function show_error(message=undefined){
    if(message){
        $("#error_message_body").html(message);
    }
    $("#error-modal").modal();

}
```

I am getting error "SyntaxError: Expected token ')' " in **Safari 5.1.7**

the HTML to include file in DJango is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/myjs.js" %}"></script>
```

the application is deployed in Heroku. I noticed that all other JS like Angular, bootstrap etc loaded from CDN have content type 'text/plain' where as myjs.js has content-type 'application/javascript'

The code works perfect in Chrome & Firefox please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is this: `function show_error(message=undefined)`. In ES6 you will be able to set default parameters but browser support is not there yet for Safari, so this will err. In your case though you don't have to set `message` to `undefined` as it will default to that if nothing is passed in. From the table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility) you can see there is still very limited support for default parameters. If you want to use default parameters I suggest looking into [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).